# For loop in trigger failing

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I am trying to loop the trigger to run for all people who are Approver 1 and send them emails.
However this is failing.
I am using apex sql workshop so cannot identify the error.

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 581
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 567
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2127


3. insert  on P_IT_ISSUES 
4. for each row 
5. FOLLOWS P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_EMAIL
6. begin
7. for c1 in
```

Trigger code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_Notify_1
AFTER 
insert  on P_IT_ISSUES 
for each row 
begin
for c1 in
(select p.person_id ,p.person_name,p.person_email,i.dept_name  from p_it_people p,p_it_departments i 
where p.assigned_dept=i.dept_id and i.dept_id=:new.related_dept_id and p.approver='Approver 1')
  LOOP
             APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
                 p_to => c1.email, 
                 p_from => c1.email, 
                 p_body =>  
                 'You have been assigned a new issue.' ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' The details are as follows ::: ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 chr(10)|| 
                 ' Department:'|| c1.dept_name ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Summary: '||:new.issue_summary ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Status: '||:new.status ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Priority: '||nvl(:new.priority,'-'), 
                  p_subj => 'New Issue '); 
           END LOOP;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

the trigger code starts at "CREATE OR REPLACE..". What are the lines above that ? The "3. insert on..., 4. ..." ? Did you include that in the source code window ? Please only post the exact code so we can understand what is wrong.
Your trigger name is 34 characters long. Change that to be less than 30 characters. This could be the cause of your issue.

A couple of tips to make your life as an oracle developer easier going forward.

1. Don't use mixed case objects names (unless you have a really good reason: "I'm used to it because it is like that in language xx is NOT a good reason). That is a syntax horror scenario. Instead use upper case only. With upper case the quotes around the object name are not needed.
2. Use the ANSI JOIN syntax vs the oracle syntax. It makes your code easier to read and there is less chance of error due to missing joins

Comment: The trigger code starts from create. Before that is the error i got in apex.

Comment: did you try with a name less than 30 characters as I suggested ?

Comment: Yes i changed the name to P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_Notify_1. The error persists.

Comment: Pls use the object browser instead of the sql workshop. You'll get much more readable error messages. Also... I strongly suggest to not use mixed case object names. A common naming conventions for triggers is: table_name_triggertiming, eg P_IT_ISSUES_BI (BI stands for Before Insert)

Comment: It worked. I used object borswer and one of my variables were incorrectly named. it was c1.person_email and not c1.email. silly mistake! thanks for advising to check object broswer. I have also made changes as per your advise and corrected name notations. Thanks again!

Comment: Why wouldn't you say "thank you" by accepting the answer, @Vini?

Comment: Because literally the error was something I figured on my own in the code. The answer has ways to write code in a proper manner and debug but it did not resolve my actual query of why the code was failing. Marking this as answr would mean it is actually the answer which it literally isn't. The answer to for loop failing in trigger is wrong variable name used in trigger.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but answer is literally what solves the problem posed in question.

Comment: IMHO the contention "answer is literally what solves the problem" is ***totally incorrect***. If a suggestion, tip, example leads you to the answer then it has answered your question. This is NOT a code writing service, it is a service provided by volunteers freely offering their time (often quite valuable time) and expertise to HELP you. The only reward for providing that service is your thanks and hopefully education (experience). So as @Littlefoot suggested accept the answer.